# Mongoose, findByIdAndUpdate, Update all except one?

Tags: express, mongoose

I could not understand, but when a User is created, date means the date of account creation. But when a User updates their information, the 'Date' is updating too. What am I doing wrong?

My model:

```
var userinfoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    type_        : String,
    firstname    : String,
    surname      : String,
    organization : String,
    name         : String,
    person_role  : String,
    members_num  : Number,
    address      : String,
    postal_code  : String,
    city         : String,
    country      : String, 
    tel          : String,
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    userinfo: [userinfoSchema]
});
```

And my app function:

```
app.put("/Edit/:id", function(req,res) {
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {$set: { userinfo: req.body.userinfo}}, 
    function(err, updated) {
        if(err) {
            res.redirect('/Edit');
        } else {
            console.log(updated);
            res.redirect('/Profil');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You mean your `date` is also updated when you update your collection? Then you have a `preUpdate` callback elsewhere

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what is it. When a user update his phone number for exemple. Date is alse updated.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you want, but from the sounds of it you're expecting the `date` field to automatically update using `pre`/`post` middleware every time an update is made.  Is that correct?

Comment: If that is the case, please include the middleware you defined.

Comment: @c1moore Hello, no it's not what I want, sorry for my english. I would like user could update every fields, and when he will click on "save", the "date" stay like before. Because the date means : the date of registration.

Comment: I added an answer, let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways you can keep the `date` the same.  The first and simplest ways is to sanitize the data from the client:

```
app.put("/Edit/:id", (req,res) => {
  delete req.body.userinfo.date;

  User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {$set: { userinfo: req.body.userinfo}}, (err, updated) => {
    // ...
  });
});
```

You should probably sanitize and verify the data anyways before saving it directly to the database, anyways.

Alternatively, you could first query for the document that needs to be updated and use the `save()`.  Your schema would look something like this:

```
var userinfoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  type_        : String,
  firstname    : String,
  surname      : String,
  organization : String,
  name         : String,
  person_role  : String,
  members_num  : Number,
  address      : String,
  postal_code  : String,
  city         : String,
  country      : String, 
  tel          : String,
  date         : {
    type         : Date,
    default      : Date.now,
    set          : (date) => {
      if(this.date) {
        return;
      }

      this.date = date;
    }
  }
});
```

To update the User, though, you would need to do something along these lines:

```
const _ = require('lodash');

app.put("/Edit/:id", (req,res) => {
  delete req.body.userinfo.date;

  User.findById(req.params.id, (err, user) => {
    if(err) {
      // Handle error.
    }

    _.assign(user, req.body.userinfo);

    user.save().then(/*...*/);
  });
});
```

Comment: Hello @c1moore, I tried your solution, but it seems not working. req.body.userinfo[0].date is not a good solution, but after searching for one week i found the ideal one. See my answer bellow if your are curious. 

Thank you very much for your time, sincerly. You could not imagine how it is a good feeling when i receive your message even when it's not the right answer. See people you didn't know trying to help us. What a good feeling. Hope i could read you again.

Answer (score 1):

**This is the best answer i think, after searching for one week...**

As of Mongoose 4.0 you can now set a **timestamps** option on the Schema to have Mongoose handle this for us:

```
var thingSchema = new Schema({..}, { timestamps: true });
```

So in this case : the model should be like this :

```
var userinfoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    type_        : String,
    firstname    : String,
    surname      : String,
    organization : String,
    name         : String,
    person_role  : String,
    members_num  : Number,
    address      : String,
    postal_code  : String,
    city         : String,
    country      : String, 
    tel          : String,
});

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    userinfo: [userinfoSchema]
}, { timestamps: true });
```

Like, we could see : date: { type: Date, default: Date.now } is not a good option to do this.

Timestamps create two fields : "createdAt" & "updatedAt" like we can see in the image below : [createdAt will never change and updatedAt will change evertytime the user will update their datas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rilTM.jpg)

NB : Also we could change "createdAt" by "date" or howether like this :

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    userinfo: [userinfoSchema]
}, { createdAt: 'date', updatedAt: 'update_date' });
```